# Why syntaxError: invalid syntax Occurs when Login to openstack dashboard?

Tags: apache, openstack, horizon

I got issue when running openstack horizon.
I failed to log in horizon after setting all requirements and i got `SyntaxError` in `/var/log/apache/error.log`.

```
mod_wsgi (pid=5342): Failed to exec Python script file '/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/wsgi.py'.
mod_wsgi (pid=5342): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/wsgi.py'.
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/openstack_dashboard/settings.py", line 239, in <module>
   from local.local_settings import *  # noqa: F403,H303
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/openstack_dashboard/local/local_settings.py", line 137
   'enable_router': False,
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why the `SyntaxError : invalid syntax` occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem after i checked the `/etc/openstack-dashboard/local_setting.py`.

```
OPENSTACK_NEUTRON_NETWORK = {
    ...
    'enable_router': False,
    'enable_quotas': False,
    'enable_ipv6': False,
    'enable_distributed_router': False,
    'enable_ha_router': False,
    'enable_fip_topology_check': False,
}
```

I didn't remove the `...` in `OPENSTACK_NEUTRON_NETWORK`.
After i remove it, the horizon works fine.